# Pass objects to a serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Here I have 2 objects recipe objects in my Recipe model. I am trying to understand what happens when I pass the recipe objects to my serializer like this. What system does to that objects? And what it returns?

```
recipes = Recipe.objects.all().order_by('-id')
serializer = RecipeSerializer(recipes, many=True)
```

And here is serializer:

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
serializer = RecipeSerializer(recipes, many=True)
```

This means that you will take the data from the `RecipeSerializer`, *not* from the model recipe; in your case, that will be the same except the form (the serializer returns data as `OrderedDict`), but in case that the serializer have more data than the model, it's going to be more useful to call the `serializer.data`.